# Why is my a ' . ' not recognized in my code?

Tags: java

```
public class NumberTester
{
    public static void main (String [] agrs)
    {
        int numberOfPhones, storagePerPhone, totalStorage;
        numberOfPhones =20; storagePerPhone =32;
        totalStorage = numberOfPhones * storagePerPhone;
        System.out.printIn("If you have");
        System.out.printIn(storagePerPhone + " storage per phone and");
        System.out.printIn(numberOfPhones + " phones, then");
        System.out.printIn("the total amount of storage is " +totalStorage);
    }
}
```

'System.out.printIn' is not being recongnized when I go to compile the code

Comment: It's not System.out.printIn.  It's System.out.println

Comment: `println` not `printIn`. Print + LN like from the word LINE. i vs L

Comment: l and I look same.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font deceived you it's `System.out.println` not `System.out.printIn`
It's `l`(small L) not `I`(capital i). Both look similar.